# oData v4 - ordering outer entity on property in related one-to-many entities

Tags: asp.net, odata

I have an oData model with a couple of one-to-many relationship, say `person->addresses` and person->driving-licences. I would like to be able to sort the result set based on properties in the address entity and driving licence entity. As there could be more than one address, I would initially select a single item from the addresses set, based on a property called `IsPrimary`. As there could be more that one driving licence, I would select the 'UK' driving licence. Is this possible?

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
/people?$expand=addresses($filter=isPrimary eq true),drivinglicences($filter=country eq 'UK')&$orderby=addresses/postcode,drivinglicences/active
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

"The query specified in the URI is not valid. The parent value for a property access of a property 'isPrimary' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is supported by the spec? Or whether it is an issue with my query? Or whether it is an issue with the .NET library.

I'm using:
Microsoft.AspNet.OData - 7.2.3

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you open to making changes to the API? As discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324393/1690217 this is not supported in the Spec, you can filter on singleton Navigation properties, but not collections

Comment: Please update your question with one or two examples of other relationships or fields you would like to filter on, that way I can make sure my suggestion solution will be viable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the post with an additional relationship. Hope that conveys what I'm trying to do. I am open to making changes to the API. When you say it's not supported in the spec - do you have a reference to this. I couldn't find anything explicit in the spec. :)

Comment: I've posted an answer,though it doesn't help much more than the previous solution. Bottom line, to achieve these types of sorting, you will have to implement a custom endpoint, which is half the fun. Although OData allows a pretty thorough query syntax, it is not expected that every OData query only uses the CRUD endpoints, sometimes the query would be more bytes across the wire than the result set itself. Try to implement a custom endpoint, or modify your client such that the sorting is done on the client, not on the server... which of course means you should have a good filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is by design, or rather not supported by the specification, the error message even highlights the only type of expressions supported:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. The parent value for a property access of a property 'isPrimary' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

So the simplest solution is to modify the API either to include a *Function* bound to the `people` collection that applies the `$filter` or `$order` directly, or a *Function* that returns the data in a new *shape*, one that only has perhaps a singleton `PrimaryAddress` property. How you include driving license in this result is up to you, it could even be a parameter to the function, perhaps your people controller has a queryable function with this signature:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult WithLicences(string countryCode)
```

However that is out of the scope of OPs question about specific syntax support

---

Although it seems like an important feature, we must remember that `$select` (*Projection*) and `$filter` are evaluated at different points in time, *OData* queries follow a similar execution sequence to *SQL* however the filter criteria and $orderby are evaluated separately, and the projection of the resultset is the last evaluation to be applied.

- Due to $filter and $orderby being applied independently, neither concept is even aware of the other and as such neither can reference or assume to be applied before the other.

You can prove this by specifying a field in the `$orderby` and/or `$filter` that is not included in the `$select`, you can even reference singleton navigation fields that are not included in an `$expand` and the query will evaluate correctly.

> The OData spec is similar to a law document, in that to properly understand and apply it we need to understand the original intent of the authors. We can get an initial understanding from the early listing of [Addressing Entities](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_AddressingEntities))
>
> > *Addressing Entities* describes *functions* that can be bound to collections or entities that return either a single entity or a collection of entities
>
> By allowing special provision of custom *functions* to be applied the authors are encouraging API designers to provide natural extensions to their resource endpoints that can facilitate the execution of pre-determined queries that may be otherwise complex or problematic to express in pure OData query syntax.
>
> > In other words, we are encouraged to customise our APIs to make them easier for the end process to consume, and to guide the consuming developer to make the best use of the API, they shouldn't have to discover everything from first principals.

To achieve OPs type of query in pure *SQL* would still require either a nested lookup, CTE or self join... advanced syntax. In OData v4, the specification does not provide a syntax for targeting specific items within a collection for path expressions (of which `$orderby` derives from)

> **[5.1.1.15 Path Expressions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_PathExpressions)**
>   Properties and navigation properties of the entity type of the set of resources that are addressed by the request URL can be used as operands or function parameters, as shown in the preceding examples.
>
> Properties of complex properties can be used via the same syntax as in resource paths, i.e. by specifying the name of a complex property, followed by a forward slash (/) and the name of a property of the complex property, and so on,
>
> Properties and navigation properties of entities related with a target cardinality 0..1 or 1 can be used by specifying the navigation property, followed by a forward slash (/) and the name of a property of the related entity, and so on.
>
> If a complex property is null, or no entity is related (in case of target cardinality 0..1), its value, and the values of its components, are treated as null.

**RE:** I couldn't find anything explicit in the spec. :)

That is the very thing about the OData specification,the specification does not list what is not supported, only what should be supported. So by omission, if you cannot find a reference to how to do *something*, then that *something* is not required to be supported.

> **Introduction** http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_Introduction ... This specification defines a set of recommended (but not required) rules for constructing URLs to identify the data and metadata exposed by an OData service as well as a set of reserved URL query string operators, which if accepted by an OData service, MUST be implemented as required by this document.

This has been on ongoing discussion held in may threads, recently https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324393/1690217 
Many people complain that this is surely a fundamental feature of a data access platform, however it is important to respect the original intent of the OData platform and keep our APIs simple by providing customised endpoints to suit our business domain.

Comment: Awesome, thorough response. Thanks. Just what I was after. I'll take a look at the api modification with custom functions and see how I get on. :)